# PHP echo multiple databse columns

Tags: php, echo

could someone let me know how to echo both the first name and the last name from `$profile_data` please ?

At the moment the page shows something like "John's Profile". However I am unsure how to add the last_name so that it shows "John Smith's Profile".

Would appreciate any help!!!

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
    $username = $_GET['username'];

    if (user_exists($username) === true) {
        $user_id        = user_id_from_username($username);
        $profile_data   = user_data($user_id, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
?>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data["first_name"]; ?>'s Profile</h1>
    <p><?php echo $profile_data['email']; ?></p>
```

---

Comment: Have you thought of using two `echo` statements?

Comment: "<h1><?php echo $profile_data["first_name"]; ?>
  <?php echo $profile_data["last_name"]; ?>'s Profile</h1>" works but I was hoping there was a shorter method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You colud do this:

```
<h1><?php echo $profile_data["first_name"] + " " + $profile_data["last_name"]; ?>'s Profile</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line to

```
    <h1><?php echo($profile_data["first_name"].' '.$profile_data["last_name"]); ?>'s Profile</h1>
```